# Issues with a jQuery thumbnail carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel, flickr

Creating a jQuery carousel that loads images from flickr. I have things mostly working, but can't seem to figure out how to stop the carousel from scrolling past the end of the images. I've been trying to calculate the width of the list that the thumbnails are in, but I can only seem to get the width of the visible area.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Eku5K/

Here's the scrolling functions...

```
var change = "250px";
$(".scroll.left").click(function () {
    var thumbLeft = thumbs.css("left");
    if ((parseInt(thumbLeft) * -1) < parseInt(change)) {
        $(".thumbs ul").animate({
            'left': "0"
        });
    } else {
        $(".thumbs ul").animate({
            'left': "+=" + change
        });
    }
});

$(".scroll.right").click(function () {
    var thumbLeft = thumbs.css("left");

    $(".thumbs ul").animate({
        'left': "-=" + change
    });

});
```

Any help?  Or suggestions on improving this?

Comment: I guess you've got problem on calling images, can't calculate its width: http://jsfiddle.net/c4byM/10/ but instead inspect this example works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7eLj4/5/

Comment: I can see all the properties of the images when I log them to the console... but can't seem to get the width of them into javascript...